# "work experiences" vs. "work experience"

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

Imagine that, I am the new manager to a team, I need to know about my team members' work history in this company and before this company.

> Last week, I reviewed all the employees' work **experiences** in my team
>
> Last week, I reviewed all the employees' work **experience** in my team

It seems that [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work%20experience%2Cworking%20experience%2C%20work%20experiences&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwork%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwork%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWork%20Experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWork%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWORK%20EXPERIENCE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cworking%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bworking%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWorking%20Experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWorking%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwork%20experiences%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwork%20experiences%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWork%20Experiences%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWork%20experiences%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWORK%20EXPERIENCES%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cwork%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwork%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWork%20Experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWork%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWORK%20EXPERIENCE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cworking%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bworking%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWorking%20Experience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWorking%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwork%20experiences%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwork%20experiences%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWork%20Experiences%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWork%20experiences%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWORK%20EXPERIENCES%3B%2Cc0) supports both

[image]

which one should I use?

---

could someone make up a situation where the other one is used? for example, if "work experience" is the correct choice for the situation above, in what situation "work experiences" should be used?

Comment: I think you should provide some more context. Is it supposed to mean you reviewed their **work experience** (a phrase for part of one's schooling before getting a proper job), or their **work history** (with other employers), or their **responsibilities** while working for you? The word **experience** is usually used as a mass noun, for example "my life experience". In relation to specific events it can be used in the plural, for example "my best travel experiences" but I would not use the plural to describe events in my work, unless relating anecdotes.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've updated my question just now, would you please take a loot at that?

Comment: I that case I would write "I need to know my team members' work history, and their experience and responsibilities in the company.

Comment: Assuming you don't know which to choose (that it's not obvious from context—something you haven't specifically provided yet), just looking at the graph you presented shows which is more commonly used. In short, you've essentially answered your own question.

Comment: To add another penn'orth, if asked at interview about my **work experiences** I would hesitate to know quite what to say, but if asked about my **work experience** I would say (for example) "I have worked for public and private corporations so I know both sides of the industry..." and so on.